# Ring of Witt vectors is a representable functor

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The map taking a ring $R$ to the ring of Witt vectors over $R$ is a functor from rings to rings.
I heard this functor is also **representable**.

How can I prove the functor is representable, and what is the merit or motivation to remark the functor is representable?
Reference (website etc...) is also appreciated.

Comment: You should not call this the Witt ring. The Witt ring is a coming from quadratic forms. This is really the ring of Witt vectors.

Comment: For instance, if you also show that the ring structure on the ring of Witt vectors is induced by a co-ring structure on the representing object (which is true, and presumably part of what it means for the functor from rings to rings to be representable), then you can pretty much automatically conclude that the ring of Witt vectors functor has a left adjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a ring. One possible way of defining the ring of Witt vectors for an $R$-algebra $A$ is to define

$$W(A) = \text{Hom}_{R}(R[T]^\mathbb{N},A)$$

where you have a very particular coring structure on $R[T]^\mathbb{N}$ giving you the group structure, and you then define the remaining ring structure separately. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: I read it in Demazure, though he does not specify it directly (he uses schemes) and so I tried translating what he does into this setting.